# How to force java server to accept only tls 1.2 and reject tls 1.0 and tls 1.1 connections

Tags: java, security, ssl, https

I have a HTTPS web service running on Java 7. I need to make changes so that this service only accepts TLS1.2 connection and reject SSL3, TLS1.0 and TLS1.1.

I have added the following Java parameter so that TLS1.2 is the highest priority.

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

but it also accepts the TLS1.0 connections from Java clients. If the client is also running with above Java parameter, the connection is TLS1.2 but if the client is running without this parameter, the connections is TLS1.0.

I did some play around the `java.security` file in `jdk/jre/lib/security` folder.

I currently have following disabled algorithms:

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms= MD2, MD4, MD5, SHA224, DSA, EC keySize < 256, RSA keySize < 2048, SHA1 keysize < 224
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=DSA, DHE, EC keySize < 256, RSA keySize < 2048, SHA1 keysize < 224
```

I am using Java 7 update 79. I am not inclined towards intercepting each connection and checking the TLS version.

My server certificate is 2048 bit generated with MD5 with RSA algorithm.

If the disabled algorithm list has RSA in place of RSA keySize < 2048, I get the `SSLHandShakeError` with error message:

> no cipher suites in common.

My test program is running the HTTP server from following URL:
http://www.herongyang.com/JDK/HTTPS-HttpsEchoer-Better-HTTPS-Server.html

Please help how to make java accept only TLS1.2 connections.

Comment: does `SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2")` work?

Comment: @user5266804 No, it does not. The `SSLContext.getInstance` method basically takes either `SSL` or `TLS` as an argument. I'll bet that under the covers, the Sun provider doesn't even care what string you pass in: you always get "the TLS engine" provided by JSSE.

Comment: sysprop `htts.protocols` didn't work because it (and `https.cipherSuites`) only affects _outgoing_ connections using `HttpsURLConnection` -- not incoming, nor direct use of `SSL[Server]Socket` or `SSLEngine`. @ChristopherSchultz: JCA lookup only accepts (ignoring case) strings predefined by the provider, which for j7 JSSE are `Default SSL SSLv3 TLS TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2` -- the latter two differ in what protocols are enabled _initially_ but all do use the same code and can enable any subset of the implemented protocols except those in `disabledAlgorithms` secprop

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I found a solution for this. I set the

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms= SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1
```

in the file `jre/lib/security/java.security` on the server.

After setting this, server only accepts the TLS1.2 connection and reject lower security protocol versions.

Comment: where to set this?

Comment: you need to set this in "java.security" file which you can find in <JDK>/jre/lib/security folder.

Comment: do i need to recompile my app after changing this file in jdk/jre/lib/security?

Comment: This changes does not require recompilation as it is not a code change.

Comment: After changing mentioned line. Do Any other command required reload the properties ?

Comment: I am using below property 
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=EC, ECDHE, DHE, TLSv1.2, SSLv3, RSA keySize < 2048

But when I get the getSupportedCipherSuites() it also display disabled Cipher

Comment: even after I had done this change, the `nmap --script ssl* -Pn -p <port> <IP>` shows that it supports the old TLS versions. do I have to restart the JVM?

Comment: @userLearner no you don't need to reload any settings.

Answer (score 3):

I have also done the same changes in `"/java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/security"-java.security` file but some of the clients are still able to call my services with SSL protocol.

Changes:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSL,SSLv2,SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1,MD5, SSLv3, DSA, RSA keySize < 2048
```

Comment: "but some of clients are still able to call my services with SSL protocol."
I love this one.

Comment: An attempted answer to this very old answer would be to add SSLv2Hello to disabledAlgorithms.

Answer (score 2):

Just a small remark;

In the question you stated that you generated a 2048 size certificate with MD5. But in the cert path alg you disabled MD5 so this normally should not work. Secondly Server certificates generated with a MD5 hash are banned from modern browsers such as Internet Explorer 10/Edge.

I would like to advice you to generate your Server certificate at least with a SHA256 or < hash.

Answer (score 2):

*Update as of November 2021*

Starting with **version 11.0.11** of the JDK, you do not need to do anything, as TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 are disabled by default.

The fix was also backported to JDK 7u301, and 8u291.

For details: [JDK-8202343 : Disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8202343)

You can still explicitly enable TLS 1.0/1.1 by changing java.security, as noted in the accepted answer.

Comment: although in j9 up `java.security` is in `conf/security` not `jre/lib/security`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than searching for and manually modifying the `java.security` file, I would suggest doing it in code e.g.:

```java
Security.setProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms", "SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1");
```

(Suggestion adapted from https://forums.oracle.com/ords/r/apexds/community/q?question=io-error-no-appropriate-protocol-protocol-is-disabled-or-ci-2571&session=206554440082745)