# Making TLS v1.2 connections on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ssl, environment-variables, tls1.2

I have a Google App Engine Java 7 server which makes HTTP connections to an API:

```
    // Setup
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(Url);
    request.setEntity(new StringEntity(Xml));

    // Execute request and extract response
    ResponseHandler<String> response = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String body = client.execute(request, response);

    return body;
```

However this is failing because the service to which I am connecting has stopped accepting TLS v1.0 and v1.1 connections, and only accepts TLS v1.2. How can I adapt my server or code to this change?

I have already seen other reports that this can be done in Java 8, but can this be done without updating the Java version?

**Update**

I have added the following just before the 'Setup' above:

```
    System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");

    Socket socket = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket();
    String[] tlsVersions = {"TLSv1.2"};
   ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledProtocols(tlsVersions);
```

However I am getting the error `Received fatal alert: handshake_failure` on Google App Engine. Can anyone advise?

Comment: If you can set java environment variable please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34609384/how-to-set-tls1-2-version-in-java

Comment: @spdev How do I set the Java environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows then set environment variable 
 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2