# Can't connect to Eclipse Marketplace

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install `log4j Eclipse Plugin`.

But I'm Getting this *error* message :

**Unable to read repository at https://sourceforge.net/projects/oneclick-logger/files/site/content.xml. Received fatal alert: handshake_failure**

Comment: Same error here, but in my case when trying to install JAutodoc plugin. The exact error is "Unable to read repository at https://sourceforge.net/projects/jautodoc/files/updatesite/1.14.0/net.sf.jautodoc.velocity_1.14.0.jar/download.
Received fatal alert: handshake_failure"

Comment: Solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38203971/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure/38264878#38264878

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue for yet another plugin hosted on SourceForge. It seems to be a common issue.

As stated in the comments above, this solution helped me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38264878. But I had to go some extra steps to find which JRE my Eclipse installation was using. So here are all the steps put together. This instructions worked on my Mac, using Eclipse Neon. But other OS and versions of Eclipse will have really similar operations:

1./ Check the JRE used by Eclipse: 
Click the "help" menu -> Installation Details -> Configuration
Then look for the `-vm` argument

2./ Open a finder/file explorer to the JRE's `.../lib/security` sub-folder
And make a backup of `local_policy.jar` and `US_export_policy.jar`. Just in case.

3./ Download the Java Cryptography Extension from Oracle:

- Java7: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html
- Java8: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

And unzip it.

4./ Copy `local_policy.jar` and `US_export_policy.jar` just just downloaded into the JRE's `.../lib/security` sub-folder

5./ Restart Eclipse

Then retry the installation. It should be fine this time.