# Trouble installing Control Flow Graph Factory

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I just found a plugin that only exists on Eclipse.

First I had some trouble with downloading via their Plugin Manager because I got "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure". Then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38203971/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure/38264878#38264878) and I solved it.

But now I get an error like this:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Bytecode Visualizer 4.5.0.201508311741 (com.drgarbage.bytecodevisualizer.feature.group 4.5.0.201508311741)
  Missing requirement: Bytecode Visualizer 4.5.0.201508311741 (com.drgarbage.bytecodevisualizer.plugin 4.5.0.201508311741) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.7.0,3.12.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Bytecode Visualizer 4.5.0.201508311741 (com.drgarbage.bytecodevisualizer.feature.group 4.5.0.201508311741)
    To: com.drgarbage.bytecodevisualizer.plugin [4.5.0.201508311741]
```

I tried to download all the files and then "Install new software" but I get the same error.

It seems to have something to do with `"bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.7.0,3.12.0)' but it could not be found"`

Tips?

Answer (score 1):

The `[3.7.0,3.12.0)` in the `org.eclipse.core.runtime` message says that a version of the plugin which is at least version `3.7.0` and **less** than version `3.12.0` is required.

Eclipse Neon has version 3.12.0 of this plugin so it won't match this requirement. So it looks like this code is not supported on Neon and requires an earlier version of Eclipse.