# Unable to read repository coder plus

Tags: eclipse, java-8, maven-3, m2eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

I cannot install the plugin [m2e-connector](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/m2e-connector-maven-dependency-plugin) on Eclipse. It complains about sun certification path.

I'm using Eclipse Oxygen dec 2017, and Ubuntu OS. The jdk 8 is updated.

[image]

The error:

```
Unable to read repository at http://coderplus.com/m2e-update-sites/maven-dependency-plugin/content.xml.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I looked at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38203971/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure/38264878#38264878). I downloaded the certifications from Oracle, but still doesn't work. Also, I'd tried this other [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625943/unable-to-read-repository-at-http-download-eclipse-org-releases-indigo).

There's any solution or alternative for this plugin?

Comment: Why do you ask such question on SO. Ask Eclipse or coderplus support. If I read the error messages right, you are not alone: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/m2e-connector-maven-dependency-plugin#undefined and https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-25742.

Comment: And see the results of an SSL tester: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=coderplus.com&latest

Comment: I posted the question here, because at first, I wanted to assure this was not a problem with the plugin itself