# Support for TLSv1.1 in jdk 1.7.0_79

Tags: java-7, tls1.2

We have tried the below code to identify the protocols supported by the java version 1.7.0_79

```
SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket soc = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket();

// Returns the names of the protocol versions which are
// currently enabled for use on this connection.
String[] protocols = soc.getEnabledProtocols();

System.out.println("Enabled protocols:");
for (String s : protocols) {
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output for the above program..

```
1.7.0_79 
Enabled protocols: 
TLSv1
```

In order to support TLSv1.1 we have tried following options

- with reference to [link](https://tonyyan.wordpress.com/2015/07/17/enabled-tls-1-2-and-tls-1-1-on-java-7/) executed program with `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2`  but it didn't work ,it show only the TLSv1.
- Then with reference to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466407/how-to-force-java-server-to-accept-only-tls-1-2-and-reject-tls-1-0-and-tls-1-1-c) we added follow line

  ```
  jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms= SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1
  ```

in java.security which didn't help as well. Could someone help  in identifying the changes to be done in jdk 1.7.0_79?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were almost there .You can disable **TLSv1.0** by adding below entries in your code for JDK 1.7.0_79

```
sslSocket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"});
```

for further explaination please refer [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/cve-2014-3566-2342133.html)

**Example**

```
SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket();
sslSocket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"});
// Returns the names of the protocol versions which are
// currently enabled for use on this connection.
String[] protocols = sslSocket.getEnabledProtocols();

System.out.println("Enabled protocols:");
for (String s : protocols) {
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

**Output**-

```
Enabled protocols:
TLSv1.1
TLSv1.2
```

**Other ways**

In addition ,if you were allowed migrating to JDK1.8 then by default it disables **TLSv1.0** and supports **TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2**