# Enabling TLS-1.2 on embedded Jetty

Tags: embedded-jetty, tls1.2

Currently I am using this code which is enabling TLS 1.2:

```java
ServerConnector httpsConnector = new ServerConnector(server, 
       new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, "http/1.1"),
       new HttpConnectionFactory(https_config));
httpsConnector.setPort(8443);
httpsConnector.setIdleTimeout(50000)
```

Now I am using TLS 1.1 and want to change it to TLS 1.2.

Comment: What version of Jetty? What version of Java? how are you checking for TLS level? What have you tried?

Comment: Hi , Jetty version is 9. I am not sure about how are you checking TLS level ? can you please elaborate and I am aiming to change the Rest service call URL from HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: Jetty 9 is insufficiently detailed.  Jetty 9.x covers currently 5 major versions of Jetty. (Jetty versioning is <servlet_support_level>.<major>.<minor>) - we need to know the Java version as well.

Comment: Its Jetty 9.2.21.v20170120 and java is java 8

Answer (score 4):

Java 8 is TLS/1.2 by default.

- https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/java_8_will_use_tls

You can diagnose TLS in the JVM using the techniques at:

- https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https

If you want to force TLS/1.2, see the prior answer at:

[How to force java server to accept only tls 1.2 and reject tls 1.0 and tls 1.1 connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466407/how-to-force-java-server-to-accept-only-tls-1-2-and-reject-tls-1-0-and-tls-1-1-c)

Know that the ciphers and protocols you expose in Jetty's SslContextFactory will also have an influence on your TLS support level. (For example: you can exclude the ciphers that TLS/1.0 knows about leaving no ciphers to negotiate against)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I resolved this question just now. 
We can customize it by `org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory` just like this:

1. exclude TLSv1、TLSv1.1 protocol etc.

```
sslContextFactory.addExcludeProtocols("TLSv1", "TLSv1.1");
```

By the way, my jetty version is 9.4.45, default protocols("SSL", "SSLv2", "SSLv2Hello", "SSLv3") have already excluded by Jetty.

```java
// org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory#DEFAULT_EXCLUDED_PROTOCOLS
private static final String[] DEFAULT_EXCLUDED_PROTOCOLS = {"SSL", "SSLv2", "SSLv2Hello", "SSLv3"};
```

2. include only TLSv1.2 protocol (some protocols etc.)

```
    sslContextFactory.setIncludeProtocols("TLSv1.2");
```

The final protocols selected you can see in the method `org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory#selectProtocols` , you can debug yourself.