# How does Wiremock determine which TLS version to use?

Tags: java, wiremock

I have a client which sends handshake request to wiremock by specifying TLS 1.2 but wiremock replies back with TLS version 1.0.
How Do I get wiremock to use version 1.2

Answer (score 4):

Did you ever find out how to make WireMock use TLS 1.2?

**EDIT:** To set up a WireMock that only supports `TLS 1.2` you have to implement your own `HttpServerFactory` that builds an instance of your custom `HttpServer`. The WireMock setup would be something like this:

```java
WireMockServer server = new WireMockServer(
    WireMockConfiguration.options()
        .httpServerFactory(new CustomHttpServerFactory())
        .dynamicHttpsPort()
        .dynamicPort());
```

**ORIGINAL:**
I found that the standard WireMock implementation uses the `JettyHttpServerFactory` which looks for the following classes: `com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.jetty94.Jetty94HttpServer` and `com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.jetty92.Jetty92HttpServer`. If one of them are found, it creates an instance of the class.

The `Jetty94HttpStarter` has higher precedence than the `Jetty92HttpStarter`.

My solution was to create a copy of the `Jetty92HttpServer` and place it in the `com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.jetty92` package in my project.

```java
package com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.jetty92;

import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.Options;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.AdminRequestHandler;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.StubRequestHandler;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.jetty9.JettyHttpServer;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.servlet.MultipartRequestConfigurer;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Jetty92HttpServer extends JettyHttpServer {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JettyStarter.class);

    public Jetty92HttpServer(final Options options, final AdminRequestHandler adminRequestHandler, final StubRequestHandler stubRequestHandler) {
        super(options, adminRequestHandler, stubRequestHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public SslContextFactory buildSslContextFactory() {
        logger.debug("Creates CustomizedSslContextFactory");
        final SslContextFactory factory = new CustomizedSslContextFactory();

        logger.debug("Exclude protocols TLS, TLSv1 and TLSv1.1");
        factory.addExcludeProtocols("TLS", "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1");

        logger.debug("Set protocol=TLSv1.2");
        factory.setProtocol("TLSv1.2");

        return factory;
    }

    @Override
    public MultipartRequestConfigurer buildMultipartRequestConfigurer() {
        return new Jetty92MultipartRequestConfigurer();
    }
}
```

I know that this works for Java 7, and it should work for Java 8. However, I'm unsure if it works with Java 9 and above, but I think it should work as expected.

I recommend the following SO posts as they contain some links that helped me:

- [Enabling TLS-1.2 on embedded Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43287071/enabling-tls-1-2-on-embedded-jetty)
- [How to programmatically set the SSLContext of a JAX-WS client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001102/how-to-programmatically-set-the-sslcontext-of-a-jax-ws-client)