# The TLS version is always defaulting to TLSv1 on Java 8

Tags: java, ssl, aix

I cannot determine how my TLS version is being overwritten running Java 8 on an AIX machine.  Have tried every parameter on the on the command to force it to TLSv1.2.

Every time I execute and look at the "debug" output I get the same ...

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1; main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, protocol_version.
```

I added TLSv1 to the "java_security" file - received a "no protocol available error".

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466407/how-to-force-java-server-to-accept-only-tls-1-2-and-reject-tls-1-0-and-tls-1-1-c  ...not a java programmer but maybe this has your answer?

Comment: Please give some details regarding the java-components you use (e.g. HttpClient or jax-ws or whatnot).

Comment: Warning: AIX means the **IBM implementation of Java**, based on but **not the same** as the Sun/Oracle/OpenJDK implementation nearly everyone else uses, _particularly_ in the area of cryptoproviders, although IMLE different doesn't usually mean less capable. Nearly all the info and advice you will find on the web, including Stack and unfortunately including me, is for the mainstream one and may not apply to IBM.